# How to avoid msbuild not to rebuild if it has assembly file is already build from another machine

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I have created MSBuild script for build automation, earlier we were doing build manually on each server.

In my build script, it has the following target

1. Download Source Code
2. Build Solution

Now in the normal workflow at the very first time, it does download source code and builds all assembly files into bin/debug folder, during this process it does change assembly version number as well which is correct because since it does not have any previous timestamp information.

Till this step everything works fine, now what I am looking is that after download source code from SVN, I will stop my build process and copy my all assembly files from the server and paste into my source code folder under bin/debug and resume my MSBuild script execution for the second target. i.e. Build Solution

Since both source code and assembly files are same no code change, how can I handle such scenario in MSBuild that not to rebuild assembly files?

I have searched on google that how MSBuild check if all assembly files are up to date? and implement following way to handle it and it works as expected. Is there any better way to handle this scenario?

```
  <Target Name="BuildSolution" Inputs="@(CsFiles)" Outputs="@(AssemblyFile)">

    <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionFile)" />
```

Comment: Afaik there is no proper clean way to do this Testing if a build is up-to-date consists of more than just checking output files: also intermediate files are considered. And you don't have them, so msbuild will consider the build out-of-date. With enough hacking you might trick it into believing it's not, but that requires a bunch of research into the core msbuild code. Just excluding the projects you don't want to build from the build in VS seems way simpler and effective than. Which is nice since your worklfow sounds complicated enough already (unless everything you say is automated)